# Problema ao instalar ngcordova no ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho um app móvel instalei o `ngcordova` para usar plugins dele mas quando tento instalar ele nunca me adiciona `lib/ngCordova` na pasta do projecto, gostava de saber como corrigir.
Para instalar estou a usar `bower install ngCordova` mas só me aparece a seguinte mensagem

**Mensagem**

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/driftyco/ionic-bower.git#1.1.0
bower resolve       git://github.com/driftyco/ionic-bower.git#1.1.0
bower not-cached    git://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova.git#*
bower ENORESTARGET  No tag found that was able to satisfy 1.1.0

Additional error details:
No versions found in git://github.com/driftyco/ionic-bower.git
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do bower que vc está utilizando?
Verifique digitando `bower -v`. Já foram [relatados](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/953) erros desse tipo na versão 1.5.1 do bower, e atualizando para a 1.5.2 resolve. Para atualizar para a versão recente `npm install -g bower`

Comment: Tente verificar no link do Github que aparece no erro e veja se a versão que está tentando instalar realmente existe. Atualize o seu arquivo **package.json** com alguma versão existente e provavelmente conseguirá instalar esse pacote.